# How to calculate how long a 9V battery will last based on schematic?

Tags: led, circuit-analysis, current

So I made this schematic for a little bathroom light I made. I would like to figure out how to calculate how long the 9V battery I connected will last with this specific schematic. The diodes are LEDs.

[image]

Here is what the Terrible Product looks like for reference:
[image]

Comment: what are those diode voltages? Zeners? LEDs? What's the 9 V battery specification?

Comment: I don't think you mean to draw your schematic like that.   You probably mean to have D5 moved such that it comes AFTER the node (close to R1)

Comment: To a first approximation, it is mAh / ma = hours of battery life. The battery should have some kind of mAh specification. The mA number comes from the current in your circuit. If you answer Neil_UK's questions, maybe we can figure out the actual numeric answer.

Comment: Remove R1 then for 9V if C= 311mAh and D6=3.5V then I= (9V-2*3.5)/330= 6mA and 311mAh/6mA=52h approx.

Comment: @Neil_UK they are white LEDs.

Comment: @mkeith - fixed. It is also just a 9V battery from amazon. Looking at the battery and instructions I don't find any type of mAh specifications.

Comment: @Neil_UK How come it would reduce battery life? Deleting R1 would cause D5 not to work, right? Sorry I am a college student studying EE, they haven't taught us anything about LEDs before.

Comment: consider the loop formed by the battery and R1. What does the current flowing through there do? Good for using component references on your schematic, but unfortunately you've re-used them for the new schematic. It would be clearer to have different references so the schematics were diasambiguated. There is a schematic editor which is very easy to use, especially for a circuit of that size.

Comment: Terrible Product? That's perfectly good Dead Bug construction technique. (But I'd snip out R1; it's only job is to shorten battery life)

Comment: Apparently the capacity of this type of cell is typically around 550 mAh (wikipedia). But Tony says 311 mAh. He usually knows what he is talking about so maybe that is more accurate.

Comment: The picture really helps. Thanks for adding that! I wish everyone would put pictures or diagrams in their questions.

Comment: @mkeith Yeah! No worries just thought I should show every thing I attempted.

Comment: Thanks, @BrianDrummond. Snipped out R1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear whether your running the LEDs at different brightness is intentional or accidental. The small difference in brightness is not large, so I'm guessing it's accidental. Two configurations that run the LEDs at the same brightness would be ...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foYL8K.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The first will operate down to the lowest battery voltage. However, the second draws half the current for the same light output, so may last longer anyway, even though the battery voltage will be higher when the LEDs reach an unusable brightness.

The nominal capacity of an alkaline PP3/6LR61 is 0.5 Ah, though it's not always clear what end voltage or what rate of discharge manufacturers are using when they test this.

If the second configuration takes 10 mA, a ballpark lifetime would be 500 mAh / 10 mA = 50 hours. That's maybe within a factor of 2 or 3 either way, given the uncertainties of how the 500 mAh is specified, whether your particular battery is a quality one or a knock-off, what your end point for subjective brightness is, and the fact that I haven't even attempted to allow for the reducing current as the battery runs down.

Comment: Ah yes. I was wondering why one was brighter than the other. I thought it was because the forward voltage from the LEDs . So the reason for this is due to the way I set up my original schematic?

Comment: You'll notice that in my schematic 1, both LED+R have the same voltage across them, so same current. In schematic 2, the resistor supplies the same current to both LEDs. In your circuit, the LED+Rs see different voltages, so the LEDs take different currents.

Comment: Oh, because they are in series and not parallel. Okay well now I am really confused because why the hell are my LEDs lighting up at all then? The current would pass through the LED before the resistor. Is current flowing in a different direction. Maybe I should just scrap this.

Comment: If you delete R1 from your schematic, you end up with my second circuit.

Comment: Your LEDs are lighting because there's a current through each. A big current through D5, and a small current through D6, because it has a lower voltage across its resistor.

Comment: Oh so the resistor aren't even doing anything then in my setup?

Comment: Do you have a DMM? This is an excellent circuit to play with to discover all sorts of things that I take for granted as intuitive, and you have yet to learn. Measure voltages round your circuit. Build both my circuits, and measure voltages round those. You can do that with a simulator as well, but it's so much more visceral with LEDs and meters.

Comment: At least one resistor is necessary in your circuit, R2, to limit the current into the LEDs. R1 is redundant, just wasting power. But it does serve to increase the current through D5, which is why it's running brighter.

Comment: Yes, I do. Okay I will. Thank you for the help. Sorry for the amateur question. I am in my junior year as an EE major and they never brought up LEDs!